# Indefinite integrals and changing variables

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Why is it legal to change the variable of an indefinite integral?

---

Consider
$$\int \dfrac{dx}{\cos x}$$

If one were to say, $\text{Let } u=\cos x$, do we not now technically have
$$\int_{u=\cos-\infty}^{u=\cos\infty}u^{-1}\dfrac{d\arccos u}{du} \cdot du$$
Which is clearly madness even before we consider that whatever $\cos \infty$ is, $\cos -\infty$ is too.

---

So my question is simply, what have I missed; why is it allowed?

Comment: If you consider $u=\cos x$ then $x=\arccos u.$ So $dx=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du.$ Where is $\arccos u$ in the integral? On the other hand, why you try to convert and indefinite integral into a definite integral?

Comment: Woops. That was a dumb error. Well an indefinite is no different to 'definite over infinite range in each direction' right?

Comment: They are completely different things. An indefinite integral is a function (if we assume some normalization on the constant of integration) and a definite integral is a number (if it exits).

Comment: But am I wrong in saying $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y(x)dx := \int y(x)dx$?

Comment: I'm not "trying to turn it into a definite integral" - I'm just asking why it is allowed to change the variable. If it was definite, the values of those bounds would also change.

Comment: Yes. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2dx$ doesn't exist but $\int x^2dx=x^3/3+c$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14498/discussion-between-manuel-fdz-lpz-and-ollie-ford)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even hint at the nature of the mysterious process that led you to the conclusion that the bounds of integration would be $\pm\infty$.  Let's try it with some actual bounds:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{\cos x} = \int_1^{\sqrt{2}/2} \frac{d\arccos u}{u} = \int_1^{\sqrt{2}/2} \frac{-du}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}
$$
No "madness" is involved.

If you want to think about $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{\cos x}$, you'll meet some unpleasant complications.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{\cos x} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)} \frac{dx}{\cos x} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{\cos x}.
$$
That last sum would be $0$ if the value of the integral is $0$ and either $\pm\infty$ if it is any other number.  So let's think about
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{\cos x} = \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} + \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \right) \frac{dx}{\cos x} = \infty + (-\infty).
$$
Perhaps one could say that a sort of Cauchy principal value of this integral is $0$.  At each of the two locations $a$ of vertical asyptotes, one would have
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\left(\int_\cdots ^{a-\varepsilon} + \int_{a+\varepsilon}^ \cdots\right).
$$
Then one would get $0$.

But one should avoid substitutions that are not one-to-one.

As to why substitutions are valid, the short answer, which you'll find in every textbook is: the chain rule.

Comment: When I was first taught to integrate, I was told $\int = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$. I never really thought too much about it again until now.

Comment: I never said there was anything mad about the definite integral, just misunderstood the indefinite.

Comment: Further, I clearly understood that the chain rule allows substitutions of definite integrals, since I applied it in my OP. There's really no need for such condescension..

Comment: What you say you were told I've never seen before.

Comment: Okay, sorry I misunderstood.. It was a while ago, I think we were taught definite first (as the application to area under curve was emphasised far more than proof), so from there I guess we were told indefinite "is like definite, but from $-\infty$ to $\infty$" or such. I don't know.

Comment: @OllieFord : I responded to what you wrote.  You asked why substitutions are valid, but then you presented an example that made it appear that your concern was that example rather than why they work in general.  Hence I wrote a very brief comment on why they work in general and wrote about your example.  If you clearly understood  that the chain rule justifies substitutions, then writing "Why is it legal to change the variable of an indefinite integral?" misleads.

Comment: I made up the example solely to demonstrate my (ill-founded and misunderstood) concern with the bounds. Almost anything would have done the same.